# Julia: How to execute a system command from Julia code?

Tags: julia

I have created a string

```
x = "ls"
```

and I wanted to execute `x` as a string from Julia. How do I do that?

`ls` is just a contrivded example I actually wanted to execute a more complicated command, so please don't tell me `pwd()` works.

The actual command might be `split c:/data/Performance_All/Performance_2000Q1.txt -n l/3 -d /c/data/Performance_All_split/Performance_2000Q1.txt`

Comment: not sure I understood your question, but will `x = @cmd "ls"; run(x)` do what you want?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can simply use `run` with a `Cmd` object. You can use strings to create `Cmd` objects via ``` `` ``` and interpolation operator `$` or through `Cmd` constructor.

Here's an example. You might want to check the file paths though.

```
x = "split"
path1 = "c:/data/Performance_All/Performance_2000Q1.txt"
option1 = "-n l/3"
option2 = "-d"
path2 = "/c/data/Performance_All_split/Performance_2000Q1.txt"
run(`$x $path1 $option1 $option2 $path2`) # remember the backticks ``
```

You do *not* need to use quotes even when there is a whitespace in the file paths. The command object runs the program and passes the parameters directly to it, not through shell.

You might want to read the relevant manual entry.
https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/running-external-programs/

Comment: I am getting IOError: could not spanw `split ..... -n l/3 -d ..... not such file or directory error. Any ideas?

Comment: As I have said in the answer, you might want to check the file paths (they seem to be wrong) and also make sure that the command `split` is in your `PATH`. Otherwise, add it to your `PATH`, make sure it is executable etc.

Comment: Maybe try to run the command directly in your shell, see if it gives any error.

Comment: Actually the `` requires that you put in the component in logical groups e.g. `m = split abc.txt def.txt; run(`m`);` will fail while `m = "abc.txt"; out="def.txt"; run(\`split $m $out\`)` will work. The same applies to options like `-d` and `-n 3/l`

Comment: you need to do `option1 = "-n l/3"; option2 = "-d"; run(\`$x $path1 $option1 $option2 $path2\`)`; if you change it I will give you the anser

Comment: My mistake. You are right! Both options gets quoted automatically in one which causes the problem. You can always print the command objects to check for an error.

Answer (score 3):

`Base::read` can be used for running a command and reading its results.

You can find usage examples for running command in the [test/spawn.jl](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/v1.1.0/test/spawn.jl)

Important is wrapping the command and its arguments in backticks. *e.g.*

```
out = ""
try
    global out
    out = read(`$x`, String)
catch ex
    @error ex
end
```